# Adding position to nodes in view results

Tags: twig, drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-templates

In Drupal 8 I have a view that shows nodes in the result. What I need is to know the order that each node has in the results list. In other words: if my node template only shows titles of those nodes.

What i need to get is something like:

1 | The title of one node

2 | The title of some other node

etc.

I was thinking of making an override of the `views-view-unformatted.html.twig`. There, I can work with the loop, but how can I have the index of the loop in the node templates?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really think you have to override anything here. You can create a new view mode for your node, e.g. teaser and manage its display using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).

Afterwards you can select rendered entity to show in your view and the corresponding view mode.

Answer (score 0):

just play with the sort criteria of your view 
it is all configurable in the back-office

```
 /admin/structure/views/view/name_of_our_view
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO loop in Twig is good solution, but in order to add numbers to your node titles you can change format to HTML List.

In format section choose **HTML List**, save, then click on **Settings** and choose "**Ordered List**"

The result should be similar to this:
[image]